# How to edit graph in xmgrace

Tags: xmgrace

I have plotted a graph using xmgrace where I am interested in two extreme portions only on x axis and I do not want to see the region in between. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide any data I created a 2-column data file `data.dat` based on the mathematical function `y(x) = 1/x` where `-2 <= x <= 2`:

```
#x  1/x
-2  -0.5
-1.99   -0.5025125628
-1.98   -0.5050505051
-1.97   -0.5076142132
[....]
```

In this plot I have already adjusted the y axis range to focus on the function around the singularity:

[image: f(x) = 1/x]

Supposing we want to plot this in xmgrace without the singularity at `x = 0`. 
I suggest the following:

1. In the "Graph Appearance" window duplicate the graph G0.
2. In the "Viewport" settings for the two graphs G0 and G1, modify the x ranges so that they sit side-by-side.
3. "Focus to" G1 by right-clicking on it and selecting "Focus to" then modify the y axis so that there is no label and no tick labels are shown.
4. Likewise, modify the axis range for both graphs so that they only show a portion of the function. For example, I chose the range `-2 <= x <= -0.01` for G1 and `0.01 <= x <= 2` for G1.

After modifying the major tick spacing this is the result:

[image: Xmgrace plot with split axes]

Unfortunately xmgrace does not have unlimited flexibility. If you want more control you could look into a scripted plotting package such as matplotlib.